# How to send an ArrayList through a socket? (TCP)

Tags: java, tcp

I've been trying to send an ArrayList through sockets to my server.

```
public class Packet00Login extends Packet
{
private String username;
private double x, y;
private int dir;
private float health;

private List<Mob> mobs;

public Packet00Login(byte[] data)
{
    super(00);
    String[] dataArray = readData(data).split(",");
    this.username = dataArray[0];
    this.x = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[1]);
    this.y = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[2]);
    this.dir = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[3]);
    this.health = Float.parseFloat(dataArray[4]);

    // this is where my problem is, I don't know how to parse it
    this.mobs = dataArray[5];
}

public Packet00Login(String username, double x, double y, int dir, float health, List<Mob> mobs)
{
    super(00);
    this.username = username;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dir = dir;
    this.health = health;

    this.mobs = mobs;
}

@Override
public void writeData(GameClient client)
{
    client.sendData(getData());
}

@Override
public void writeData(GameServer server)
{
    server.sendDataToAllClients(getData());
}

@Override
public byte[] getData()
{
    return ("00" + this.username + "," + this.x + "," + this.y + "," + this.dir + "," + this.health + "," + this.mobs).getBytes();
}

public String getUsername()
{
    return this.username;
}

public double getX()
{
    return this.x;
}

public double getY()
{
    return this.y;
}

public int getDir()
{
    return this.dir;
}

public float getHealth()
{
    return this.health;
}


public List<Mob> getMobs()
{
    return this.mobs;
}
 }
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at what `this.mobs.toString()` produces.

Comment: @BenvanGompel If there's no mobs in the list yet it's just [], otherwise it has their id in it (com.ultraboodog.entity.mob.Dummy@4e9a8f98).

Comment: You should have a look at (1) Serialization and (2) `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Yes, serialization will help.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is: use [Gson](https://www.google.com/search?q=gson%20deserialize%20list&oq=gson&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i59l2j69i60j0.1000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=gson) to serialize your `Packet00Login` object to a`String` object and send it over network, then at other side retrieve `String` object and use `Gson` to deserialize it to `Packet00Login` object.

Comment: Is that the only way to send a List through?

Comment: @UltraBoodog that is not only way but is easy way.

Comment: Alright, I just don't understand Gson. I got the arraylist into strings like this: [com.ultraboodog.entity.mob.SmartChaser@1bd1c2b5
 com.ultraboodog.entity.mob.Shooter@15162fbf] so I was wondering if there is a way to add those Strings into the List<Mob>

Comment: @UltraBoodog if you don't understand Gson, i suggest use study it, it is very useful library.